# How to compile OpenSSL for ARM64 Windows

Tags: windows, openssl, arm64

I am trying to build OpenSSL for a windows-arm64 machine.

Unfortunately, I could only find instructions on how to build it for intel architecture (and it looks like they use NASM which is intel only)...

I am quite sure that it can be built for arm64 as it can be built for android and various other arm platforms... but how to build it as a .dll for a windows arm machine?

Thanks,
Cyrille

Answer (score 1):

I could build OpenSSL 1.1.1 using vcpkg and running the Visual Studio 2022 toolchain under emulation on a Surface Pro X.

If using vcpkg is an option for you, building OpenSSL is as straightforward as typing:

> vcpkg install openssl:arm64-windows

Does this help?

Comment: Hello,

Thanks for the info, I will give it a try as a plan B.
I was able to build following (loosely) the instructions on the open sll site, but I had to do a lot of tinkering too... and I was not able to run the test suite, but I did get the binaries...

Cyrille

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two ways to build OpenSSL natively on Windows Arm64.

The first and **the best performing on Arm64** option involves using clang-cl, which can be installed from the VS installer. This option allows to use Arm64 assembly optimization. Prior to executing `nmake`, it may be necessary to add the path to LLVM, which contains clang-cl. Additionally, perl will be required, and Strawberry Perl can be used to install perl on Windows. Follow these steps for this option:

1. Run the following command to configure OpenSSL with clang-cl:

   ```
   perl Configure VC-CLANG-WIN64-CLANGASM-ARM
   ```
2. Execute the `nmake` command to initiate the build process.

The second option is to use VS 2022, which supports Arm64 target. By using VS and perl, you can build OpenSSL natively, although most of Arm64 optimization will be missed.

Here's the command sequence to follow for this option:

1. Run the following command to configure OpenSSL with Visual Studio:

   ```
   perl Configure VC-WIN64-ARM
   ```
2. Execute the `nmake` command to initiate the build process.

For more detailed instructions on both options, you can refer to the following workflow: [GitHub Workflow](https://github.com/Windows-on-ARM-Experiments/openssl/pull/1/files)